# Conditional statement mysql based on first character in string for username field

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a database where I hope to have two user types, basically I want to create a conditional statement based on the first character in sequence ($str[0] ) within the username field. e.g if username begins with 'A' redirect to a.html else username begins with 'B' redirect to b.html.

I have made a basic attempt and this but failed,

```
  if($myusername==$str ==='a:0;') {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";

} else if ($myusername==$str ==='b:0;'){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_two WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
}
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: I see nothing to account for "the first character" in your code. Can you explain more your requirement or write a pseudo code on what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I need to create a login with two session areas, I am trying to trigger an sql statement using the first character of the username string

Answer (score 0):

Just to split up what I think your problem is:

**How selecting first character of a string works:**

```
$string = "abc";
echo $string[0];
// This will output: "a"
```

**Comparing two conditionals with the same variable**

```
if($myusername === $str && $myusername[0] === 'a') {
  // Do something..
}
```

Im still not quite sure if I understand what you want to achieve, but at least this should guide you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, the a:0; appears to be coming from variables being parsed and giving you more than just the value you want.

What you really want is to just read the value directly (IE, how are you reading this value?) and check if the first character is what you want:

```
$myusername = $_POST['username'];
```

To redirect based upon the first character, it would look like this:

```
$firstChar = substr($myusername, 0, 1);

if ($firstChar == "a")
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
elseif ($firstChar == "b")
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_two WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
```

If you have more than two options you would probably want to do a switch statement instead of an "if."